# Pandas subset by index closest to a particular value

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering how to subset a DataFrame for the index closest to a particular value. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)

df.index = np.random.randn(len(df.index))
closest_to = 0
df.loc[df.index.difference([closest_to]).min()]
```

This subsets for the index furthest below 0, but I am looking for the absolute difference closest to zero.

**EDIT**:
Adding `df.loc[abs(df.index.difference([closest_to])).min()]` works when the closest value is positive, but obviously gives a KeyError for when a negative value is the closest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which isn't very neat but does the job.

```
closest_to = 0
idx = abs(df.index.difference([closest_to])).min()
if idx in df.index:
    pass
else:
    idx = -idx
df.loc[idx]
```

Comment: You got to the same solution than I, but a different implementation. ;-)